# How to add dynamically HTML element using JavaScript and Firefox Add-on SDK

Tags: javascript, jquery, httprequest, firefox-addon-sdk

I am developing a simple add-on with Firefox SDK that allows the user to review the stored data.
I would like to show the items in a panel with a table. The table is created dynamically with the data incoming from the data-base. Firstly, In the JavaScript code I create the items with their properties, then I create a table with the properties as row and I append the items with the value of each properties.

I have some problems: the table has only the item's name as first row and the properties name as first column without the value in the cells. It seems that the code is not executed in order, but it seems that the faster functions are executed first.

This is the code:

```
       self.on('message', function() {
        var container = $('#container');
        container.empty();
        items = [];
        self.port.emit('getItem');
    });

    self.port.on('items', function(response) {
        var ok = 0;
        var items = [];
        var table = $('#tableContainer #table').clone();
        var container = $('#container');

        table.append("<tr id=first><th>    </th></tr>");
        var json = eval('('+ response + ')');
        for (var i = 0, len = json.length; i < len; ++i) {
            var item = {
                id: json[i],
                properties: []
            };
            items.push(item);
        }
        items.forEach ( function(item) {    
            table.find('#first').append("<th id="+item.id+">"+item.id+"</th>");

            self.port.emit('detailsItem', item.id);
            self.port.on('details'+item.id,  function(response) {
                var details = eval('('+ response + ')');
                var description = [];
                ndet = details.length;
                var len = details.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < len;) {
                    var detail = {
                        dimension : details[i].dimension,
                        value : details[i].value
                    }
                                    description.push(detail);
                    ++i;
                }
                item.properties = description;  
            });
            });
        self.port.emit('getDimension'); 
            self.port.on('dimension', function(response) {
                var dimensions = eval('('+ response + ')');
                for(var cont = 0, l = dimensions.length; cont < l; ++cont) {
                    table.append("<tr id=dimension"+cont+"><td>"+dimensions[cont]+"</td></tr>");    

                    items.forEach( function(item) {
                        var prop = [];
                        prop = item.properties;
                        var lun = prop.length;
                        for( var p =0;p < lun;) {
                            if(item.properties[p].dimension == dimensions[cont]) {                              table.find('#dimension'+cont).append("<td>"+item.properties[p].value+"</td>");
                            }
                            else {
                                table.find('#dimension'+cont).append("<td> --- </td>");
                            }
                            ++p;                        }

                    });

                };
        });

            container.append(table);

        });
```

Comment: All of the port communication is asynchronous -- you cannot rely on the order of these events.

Comment: Also, as a general observation unrelated to your question but part of your sample code: Do not use `.innerHTML` (`$(<html>`, `.html(<html>)`, `.append(<html>)`) with unsanitized, dynamically composed HTML strings. This is essentially a potential security vulnerablity similar to SQL injection, just for html. Should you desire to upload your add-on to addons.mozilla.org later, the add-on would likely rejected for these insecure uses. Use something that will escape your stuff properly instead, e.g. `.append($("<th>", {id: "someid"}).text("sometext"));`.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any suggestion about how I can populate a table dynamically? How can I resolve the problem of the asynchronous communication?